# Laravel file_put_contents error on chrome only

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome

New to Laravel.
I have a generic Laravel application created using compose running on my local pc.
I have also added the authorisation to have login and register.
To create this specific problem I have deliberately introduced an error into the register process and it throws an SQLSTATE error. Note: I am not trying to resolve the SQLSTATE error. This is just a way to show up the issue. Please read the error below that I am trying to fix.

The steps:

1. Go to the home page (https://localhost/)
2. Attempt to register (https://localhost/register <- throws introduced error.
3. Go back to home page (https://localhost/)

The problem is in step 3. On Microsoft Edge I get back to the home page ok. But doing step 3 in Chrome it throws the following error:

> file_put_contents(D:\developer\website\storage\framework/sessions/hKn3SmXJMXmABLkv1GDkyn7Z1akun03fsf60es6D):
>   failed to open stream: Invalid argument

The error occurs at line 122 of vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php

```
120 public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
121    {
122        return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
123    }
```

As stated before this is a difference between how Edge handles getting back from an error compared to Chrome.

So my question is two fold.

a) suggestions on how to resolve the difference between browsers.

b) why is the path passed to file_put_contents contain a combination of backslash and forwardslash paths? Does it matter?

Other info:
Windows 10
apache 2.4.33
laravel 5.6
php 7.2